# Find out whether function returns true or false

Tags: forms, validation

I am struggling to make form validation work and it looks like the main problem is *placeOrder* function (other function which sit inside this functions work just fine). The function behaves in a strange way (gives alert only if the first input field (message) does not confirm to the test conditions, while if I leave the others blank it does not show alert). I was trying to find the reason for that by putting each part of the main if statement (which are divided by AND operators) in this test:

```
if(validateLenghtData(5, 32, form["message"], form["message_help"])) {
    console.log("validation passed");
} else {
    console.log("validation failed");
}
```

This gave me nothing because it only returns false ("validation failed") to console, while it outputs nothing if I enter valid text to the input. Where can  be the bug and how can I test each part of big `if` statement ( like `validatedZipCode(form["zipcode"], form["zipcode_help"])`) in order to find out which part gives me false.

```
function placeOrder(form) {

    // first check whether all fields are filled with valid data
    // form["message"] and other simular arguments are part of form object and are passed from submit form (look it)
    if (validateLenghtData(5, 32, form["message"], form["message_help"]) &&
        validatedZipCode(form["zipcode"], form["zipcode_help"]) &&
        validateNonEmptyField(form["date"], form["date_help"]) &&
        validateNonEmptyField(form["name"], form["name_help"]) &&
        validateNonEmptyField(form["phone"], form["phone_help"]) &&
        validateNonEmptyField(form["email"], form["email_help"]))       {

        // everything is ok, submit the order to the server
        form.submit(); 
    } else {
        alert ("You need to feel all fields correctly");
    }

    if(validateLenghtData(5, 32, form["message"], form["message_help"])) {
        console.log("validation passed");
    } else {
        console.log("validation failed");
    }

  }
```

Comment: Are you able to submit the form?

Comment: I don't have any PHP code for this form so I am not sure about that, but it looks lt allows to form to be submitted even with blank fields